# Is there a way to log accesses files and folders on FreeNAS shares?

Tags: linux, freenas

How do you log all files and folders accessed through FreeNAS? I manage a FreeNAS that has multiple shares accessed by multiple people on multiple OS's (Mac, Win, Linux). I'm trying to keep a detailed access log that shows:

- who accessed file
- what file they accessed
- the time
- and the action (read, modified, deleted)

Can this be done in a way that will work on FreeNAS host or any Linux system that is sharing files?

Comment: FreeNAS is FreeBSD based, not (GNU/)Linux based.

Comment: @yarl, i'm aware of that. thanks for pointing it out anyway. The reason i have both is i'm ok with an answer that applies to either. I'm in a position to change host to a custom Linux based if needed to enable more detailed logging for security reasons. FreeNAS/FreeBSD solution is preferred because that's where our main shares are.

Answer (score 1):

I ran accross this today and the following still works in FreeNAS 11

[Reference thread](https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/is-there-a-way-to-log-accesses-files-and-folders-on-freenas-shares.69768/)
[Another thread with different options](https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/tutorial-add-full-logging-on-samba-shares-full_audit-freenas-9-3.13840/)

> Are you using SMB as your sharing protocol?
>
> If so you can add the below to the SMB Aux parameters
>
> ```
> full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S 
> full_audit:priority = notice
> full_audit:failure = connect 
> full_audit:success = open mkdir unlink rmdir rename
> ```
>
> and then add the [VFS Object](https://www.ixsystems.com/documentation/freenas/11.2/sharing.html#avail-vfs-modules-tab) `full_audit` to the share.

The actions are `open mkdir unlink rmdir rename`. I couldn't find any clear documentation on SMB Aux parameters. For example `opendir` and `open` appear to do the same thing. Or at least on my system `open` logs opening files and opening directories. FreeNAS links to [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=smb.conf) but I couldn't find any of the `full_audit` configs there. [This link](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_full_audit.8.html) and [this](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_audit.8.html) provides some of the parameters but without definition.

You'll see the data in `tail -f /var/log/messages` and will need more detailed docs to reduce the logs to what you need without all the duplicate and useless logs this generates.